# firebase query based on child prop value and get path

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am new to firebase and want to pass a value of a child property, query my entire database and get the path that data is at. data is nested several levels, for example I want to query by dcid and have the path it is at returned.I have tried a few things and no dice. How can I do this with firebase? 
[image]

Here is what I've tried

```
$scope.ref = new Firebase(url);
$scope.ref.orderByChild("num").equalTo(dcid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key(), snapshot.val());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the path you're referencing:

```
snapshot.ref().toString();
```

It can be useful to check if you're looking at the correct branch of the tree. Hope this helps.

Comment: That works to get the base path but I need the full path, including the dynamic keys firebase crates

Comment: I need this too, how do we get the full path please?

Answer (score 0):

The data you added isn't compliant to the Firebase structure...

There are no arrays, only objects.

When you use `orderByChild` firebase will look for the key in a child location of the reference you called the method on.

For ex

```
new Firebase('<your-project-url>').child('items').orderByChild('prop1').equalTo('value13')
    .on('value', function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.ref().toString(), snapshot.val());
    })

{
    "items": {
        "item1: {
            "prop1": "value11",
            "prop2": "value21"
        },
        "item2: {
            "prop1": "value12",
            "prop2": "value22"
        },
        "item3: {
            "prop1": "value13", // <----- The query will find this field
            "prop2": "value23"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find the entire path as an array here:

```
snapshot.query.EP.path.segments
```

this is an array containing each step of the path. so if the actual path is for example `foo/bar/baz`, this will show as `["foo","bar","baz"]`, which obviously you can read out with

```
snapshot.query.EP.path.segments[0] //"foo"
snapshot.query.EP.path.segments[1] //"bar"
snapshot.query.EP.path.segments[2] //"baz"
```